# problems with importing org.joda.time in AndroidX

Tags: java, android, import

I just upgraded my project to AndroidX and I get error message

> error: package org.joda.time does not exist

when want to

```
import org.joda.time.Period.
```

But when run old version of my project, before migrating to androidX, all work perfect. My Android Studio can find the package.

Any suggestion how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

app/build.gradle file, add :

```
dependencies {    
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add below line in **app** level `build.gradle` file `(app/build.gralde)`

```
dependencies {    
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'
}
```